# Globalizable Galois representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, galois-representations, langlands-conjectures

Let $\rho$ be a $p$-adic representation of $G=\text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

When does $\rho$ extend to a representation of the global galois group? What can be said about the locus of such "globalizable" representations?

Comment: If you fix a nice enough $2$-dimensional mod $p$ representation $\rho$ of $Gal(\overline Q / Q)$, then there is an attached deformation space, which is usually of dimension $3$. On the other hand, you can restrict $\rho$ to $Gal(\overline Q_p / Q_p)$ and the corresponding space is of dimension $5$. There is a restriction map from the first to the second, and your question is: what does the image look like?